# How to modify app expose to show only open windows of current application on current desktop?

Tags: macos, desktop, mission-control, expose

I have OS X 10.8.5. I typically have several windows of some applications open on more than one desktop. When using App Expose, it shows all of the open windows of the current application on all Desktops. Mission Control shows all open windows, regardless of application, on the current desktop but the windows are overlapping. I want to have a way to show just the windows, without overlapping, of the current application on the current desktop.

Comment: Any luck with this question? I am struggling with this too.

Comment: No, I still don't know how to do I what I asked about? It seems bizarre to me that this feature is not the standard available features given what we can already do with Mission Control and App Expose.

Comment: I'm using El Capitan and I'm experiencing this behavior. I'm looking for a solution too. I tried the thing described at http://www.cultofmac.com/222200/customize-mission-control-to-show-only-windows-from-current-desktop-space-os-x-tips/ and it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> will show all the windows of the current app regardless of their desktop (without overlapping)

And if you want to show all the windows(can be of diff apps) of your current desktop without overlapping then uncheck the `Group windows by applicaiton` check box and your mission control will not overlap the windows

#### P.S. I have 10.9.4 installed.

[image]

Comment: @Rathore, when I try that it still shows windows from other desktops. It seems to be the same thing as App Expose, which I am guessing is what `Application Windows` is.

Comment: So you want to show all the windows of current desktop without overlapping them, right?

Comment: Yes. Do you have that application open on other desktops? If so, then perhaps I need to upgrade.

Comment: Ben I have updated my answer.

Comment: Yes ben I have opened multiple windows of same app on multiple desktops and when I press ctrl+arrow_up key it shows all the windows

Comment: Thanks. That does show the windows without overlapping, but for me it also shows windows from other applications. That is an improvement. Another thing is that this method is using Mission Control which takes off the labels of the individual windows. For example, if I have say several word documents then the saved named for each appears below when using App Expose but not Mission Control. I would like to keep the names of the files below to help locate the right window quickly.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't want to see the windows from other desktops. So I was asking if you had other windows open on other desktops, from the same application, and if only the ones on the current desktop were showing. I basically want a modified form of App Expose (control + down) that restricts itself to the current desktop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16214/discussion-between-ben-allgeier-and-inder-kumar-rathore).

Comment: Then unchecking `Group windows by applicaiton` will do the 80% percent of the trick, it will show all the windows in the current desktop.

Comment: also other app windows will be shown if you these in your current desktop

Comment: Yes I know. I don't understand how what I am asking for is not a built-in option. Why wouldn't you use, say, safari windows on several desktops along with other applications?

Comment: If Apple wasn't dumb, they could add this option. But they're dumb. I still use macOS though because at least it just works (minus the caveats, but they are less caveats than, for example, building your own Linux desktop exactly how you want it).