# Mission control: Show all application windows in current desktop only

Tags: macos, desktop, mission-control

How can I see all windows which belong to the same app in some desktop? (in OSX 10.9-10.10)

I know about `Mission Control -> Application windows` but it shows all windows from all desktops.

Say I have TextEdit with 5 windows opened (window1, window2, ...) in 2 different desktops. Window1 and window2 are in desktop1 and Window3,4,5 are in desktop2. Desktop2 is a current desktop. How do I see windows3,4,5 of TextEdit in desktop2 in a similar/same manner as `Application windows`?

Possibly a duplicate of [How to modify app expose to show only open windows of current application on current desktop?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141014/how-to-modify-app-expose-to-show-only-open-windows-of-current-application-on-cur)

Answer (score 3):

**It is simple. You don't.**

*I have MAC 2 months and Iv heard UX of MAC is gorgeous so I went for it. But for some strange reason MAC has 95% of UX realy awesome as I would expect the top UX to be BUT, there are still those 5% :( And I am not talking about some hard to use UX elements or hidden tasks. Those 5% are everyday usage UX errors MAC has. And when I say error I mean it, its not like I prefer Windows or Linux way, its that human has some "limitations" and for many tasks the "best" UX already exists but in Apple there sits some UX manager (propably few of them) and he thinks like this: "Hmm, we have to differ on as many levels as possible so we are not the same as competition" - so they take that UX, tweak those 5% of it, so it looks different.*

*How do I know that? Well ofc, I dont, but is there any other logical explenation for that and theese other examples:*

*App window control buttons on the left side? Yes its briliant - your mouse moves are limited, so your work is faster. It takes a while if ur not used to it, but it is realy good idea and its faster. But now - what will those 3 buttons acutually do? Quit app / minimize app / maximize app? Noooo, that would be too easy for everyone, lets make it different, lets make close button to close only "windows" of the app not entire app and lets leave the top bar of app hanging there so everyone can switch to it and be confused where is his focus, cause he sees the app below but it doesnt have focus right...? Minimize? Yea, it does minimize - did they notice, that minimize and close does the same thing? (It actually doesnt - but the result is the same, so "why....?) Nope they didnt. And maximize? No, why would someone want to maximize, lets make it fullscreen, cause thats the button every person needs, right...? But one brave manager raised hand and said: "But there are still ppl who actually want to maximize the window". "Hmm, ok lets keep it there with some wier shortcut, BUT lets not maximize to cover all screen, I think it is better to maximize only what we think is the best for the user. With more windows opened at once, its gonna be so messy but we dont care about it. And heh, guys, Iv got an idea, lets make a nice little prank, I think it would be hillarious to leave 1px space at the top and bottom of the screen, you know just to have fun of them :D. Every user who spends 1500$ or more will appreciate that! Its gonna be so funny to see them in their chairs asking why would someone do that :D"*

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment, but the answer is incorrect.

Comment: It's my 3rd month of using MacOS, and it's exactly how I feel. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's called App Exposé.

**Using your trackpad (and not your "magic" mouse):**

Select the application then swipe up with three fingers on your trackpad or swipe down with four fingers on your trackpad. You must have this enabled in Trackpad Preferences.  Find it under the More Gestures tab.

**Using your keyboard:**

The keyboard shortcut is control down-arrow ˆ↓
You must have the Applications Windows shortcut enabled.  Find it under the Shortcuts tab of your Keyboard preferences.

Comment: No. This is the behavior the OP wants to avoid. It brings in windows from other desktops. In his example, your suggestion shows windows 1-5, not windows 3-5, as the OP is asking.