# How to show application windows only for current Space in Exposé, and not aggregated from all Spaces

Tags: mojave, spaces, mission-control, productivity, expose

I just started using **Spaces** in **10.14** (I know I'm a little late to) and was excited at first until I encountered this scenario:

When I am in a **Space** and do **Exposé** to "Show me ALL *Application* Windows", **Exposé** shows me **ALL** the windows opened for that App across ALL Spaces (and not just from the current **Space**)

However, the behavior in the next scenario is perfect:
When I am in a **Space** and do **Exposé** to "Show me ALL Windows for ALL running applications", **Exposé** dutifully shows me only the relevant windows for "**ALL**" running applications in the "**Current**" space only. - GREAT!

The problem with showing me "All Windows for Current Application Across ALL Spaces" easily overwhelms me, and to me it cancels out the usefulness of **Spaces** to organize productivity & workflow.

I created my **Desktops** to keep things separate.

If anyone has has any insight please share- would love to use **Spaces**!

---

**Info on my research**

I found this article and these 2 Stack Articles:

[Customize Mission Control To Show Only Windows From Current Desktop Space](https://www.cultofmac.com/222200/customize-mission-control-to-show-only-windows-from-current-desktop-space-os-x-tips/)

[Exposé in 10.7: When exposing “Application Windows”, how do you show only the windows in the current space?](https://superuser.com/questions/315896/expos%C3%A9-in-10-7-when-exposing-application-windows-how-do-you-show-only-the-wi)

[How to modify app expose to show only open windows of current application on current desktop?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141014/how-to-modify-app-expose-to-show-only-open-windows-of-current-application-on-cur)

I thought I'd try to add the `wvous-show-windows-in-other-spaces` back in to my `plist`

`edited ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dock.plist -> added xml value`

```
    <key>wvous-show-windows-in-other-spaces</key>
    <false/>
```

`killall Dock`

But did not work.

Comment: Looking for the same solution for years but macOS still doesn't provide such a feature. I don't see what is the benefit of spaces  if I still see all open(It might be 10 +) from all spaces and need to scan by eye every time I open the application window

Comment: Another thing that I am missing is the fixed position in mission control. Every time I open mission control applications are rearranged in random positions and you need to scan by eye where is the desired application window.